# Getting NoSuchMethodError for com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of when running Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, guava

When I attempt to run the following code:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of( java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object,) com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap,
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.AddHasCasting.getAdditionalCommands(AddHasCasting.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.getExtraCommands(ChromeDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:50)
    at com.powin.*****.****.LoginTest.Login(LoginTest.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at 
...
```

I've tried adding the dependencyManagement fields to my pom.xml but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Here's the relevant packages in my pom.xml.

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
</dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Here's my **system information**:

Java 1.8.0_351

Mac OSX 12.6.2

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 4.26.0

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The method signatures ends with `java.lang.Object,)` which does not make sense. Please show the original and complete stack trace. Also your `pom.xml` snippet looks broken by containing `</dependencies></dependencyManagement><dependency>`. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a complete `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

editing your `pom.xml` and maven update will resolve this issue.

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
</dependency> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```